# How to display date format using Python logging module

Tags: python, logging, format

I am trying to setup a format for logging in python:

```
import logging,logging.handlers
FORMAT = "%(asctime)-15s %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT,level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger("twitter")
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('/var/log/twitter_search/message.log', maxBytes=1024000, backupCount=5)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Basically, logging works, but without the date format...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can add the `datefmt` parameter to `basicConfig`:

```
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT,level=logging.INFO,datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Or, to set the format for the Rotating FileHandler:

```
fmt = logging.Formatter(FORMAT,datefmt='%Y-%m-%d')
handler.setFormatter(fmt)
```

Comment: `datefmt` is passed on to `time.strftime()` internally: see the relevant [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) for all valid format strings.

Answer (score 2):

**Basic example:**

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
)

logging.info('Just a random string...')
# 2030-01-01 00:00:00 INFO Just a random string...
```

If you want to adjust the line spacing between **levelname** and **message** change the *%(levelname)s* like the example:

```
... %(levelname)-10s ...
# 2030-01-01 00:00:00 INFO           Just a random string...
```